# Access variables in routing page controller declared in different controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the variable from different controller written in another JS file linked. I want to display page tittle assigned from different controller. If i route to extract.html, i have to display "Extract Home" text in html tittle, I declared this variable inside the extract.js

Pls help me, thanks in advance

Main.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="routing" ng-controller="landingCtrl">
<title>{{page_location_text}} - Noble Institute</title>

<body>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>


 <script>

var routingApp = angular.module("routing", ["ngRoute","extract"]);
routingApp.controller("landingCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.page_location_text = $scope.page_location;
});
routingApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "index.html"
    })
    .when("/extract", {
        templateUrl : "extract.html",
        controller : "extractCtrl"
    });

});
</script>
```

Extract.js for Extract.html

```
 <script>

  var app = angular.module('extract',   ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',"ngSanitize", "ngCsv"]);
   app.controller('extractCtrl',function($scope, $http, $routeParams, filterFilter){
  $scope.page_location = "Extract Home";
   });

  </script>
```

Comment: You declared a page_location in extract module controller so u cannot get from parent by using $scope directly. you can use $rootScope.page_location instead of $scope. Or you can write service for that.

Comment: Might consider using `$routeChangeSuccess` event in top controller and extract title from routing config

Comment: Thanks you so much Gitesh.. I got perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set title with your route and put title on html like :

```
<title ng-bind="title">myApp</title>
```

and set title inside your route config like :

```
 .when("/extract", {
        title : 'Extract Home',
        templateUrl : "extract.html",
        controller : "extractCtrl"
    });
```

and set a run method in for your angular app :

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        document.title = $route.current.title;
    });
}]);
```